# pushing each checkbox selected data into array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to push the value of each check box value inside the array but every it pushes same data twice or as many checkbox i select if I choose 3 checkbox and the last check has the value of 2 so it is pushing 3 into the array 3 times and not storing the value of other two

The Jquery Code:

```
$('#data_table').append("<tr>"+"<td><input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' name='check' id='checked_box"+j+"' value='"+time+" 'onclick='myFunction(this)' ></td>" +"<td>"+sites.siteName +"</td>"+ "<td>" + values.deviceName + "</td>" + "<td>" + values.count + "</td>"  + "<td>" + parseFloat(time).toFixed(2) + " Min"  + "</td>" + "</tr>");
```

The Javascript Code:

```
var check_id=e.getAttribute('id');
var time = document.getElementById(check_id).value;
var values = [];
 for(var j=0 ; j<time.length ; j++){
    if(checkboxes[j].checked){
      values.push(time);
    }
  }
 console.log(values);
```

> I just want to get the checkbox values and add it up and show the
> total but as i mentioned it is pushing the same data as many times i
> select a checkbox

Please solve this problem for me,
Any help will be highly appreciable......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are pushing `time` into the array, which is the value of the checked box, not the values of each checkbox individually.

You would need to change your code to set `time` in the loop, instead of outside it. Then again, I'm not sure what you're trying to do with it, so I've had to make some assumptions as well as a few changes to make this work like I think you want it to.

```js
var time = new Date().getSeconds();
var values = [{deviceName: "laptop"},
{deviceName: "desktop"},
{deviceName: "tablet"},
{deviceName: "cell"},
{deviceName: "fablet"}];

var sites = [{siteName: "StackExchange"},
{siteName: "Google"},
{siteName: "AltaVista"},
{siteName: "AskJeeves"},
{siteName: "InfoSeek"}];

for (var j = 0; j < values.length; j++)
{
$('#data_table').append("<tr>"+"<td><input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' name='check' id='checked_box"+j+"' value='"+time+" 'onclick='myFunction(this)' ></td>" +"<td>"+sites[j].siteName +"</td>"+ "<td>" + values[j].deviceName + "</td>" + "<td>" + values.count + "</td>"  + "<td>" + parseFloat(time).toFixed(2) + " Min"  + "</td>" + "</tr>");
}

function myFunction(e)
{
var checkboxes = $(e).closest('form').find(':checkbox');
var values = [];

 for(var j=0 ; j<checkboxes.length ; j++){
    if(checkboxes[j].checked){
      values.push(checkboxes[j].value);
    }
  }
 console.log(values);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<table id='data_table'></table>
</form>
```